# Conditional color scale not working with functions

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting, regexextract

I want to apply conditional color scale but it doesn't work. This is the original cell (A12)in a sheet called `ProcessedData`:

```
= votes:[2074
```

Then, I use in B4:

```
= REGEXEXTRACT(ProcessedData!A12&".";"\b+[0-9]+\b")
```

to convert it to only numbers, so I have `2074` in the cell.

But it doesn't work with the conditional color scale. It only works if I write the number manually, and that isn't useful for me.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I actually solved it.
The answer is using VALUE() to convert a string to number, so using:

> =VALUE(REGEXEXTRACT(ProcessedData!A12&".";"\b+[0-9]+\b"))

It works perfectly.